# Magento - Customize Category Page

Tags: magento, customization, theming

I would like to add more information about the category, but at the bottom. After the products are laid out.

I know there is a description at the top where I can edit it, but I would also like to add more information at the bottom after the products. The information, pics, etc will be different per category.

Any ideas where I go about getting this done?

Thanks

p.s. im using avalanche skin

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by creating static block.For each category you can do static block from admin **cms->static block** and then at category page where you want to show content of static block base on that current category.

you can get current category base on that current category you can call the particular static block and like that you can able to display content base on categories.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('yourblockid')->toHtml(); ?>
```

using above you can able to get static block content on template file.

and using this you can get current category information

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory() ?>
```

one suggestion i would like to give you try to set static block name same as category name so it's easy for you to call the static block base on category name too using condition.

hope this ans will hellp you. let me know if you still facing any issue.

Comment: I tried this: `<?php if(getCurrentCategory()="Category Im Looking for"): ?>
  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('static_block_i_created')->toHtml(); ?>`

but results in a blank products list.

Comment: try like this <?php if(Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()=="Category Im Looking for"):?>  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('static_block_i_created‌​')->toHtml(); endif;?>